# Airflow and Spark

Tags: apache-spark, airflow

I hava airflow cluster and spark cluster, when i submit my job

```
    task_id='flight_search_ingestion',
    conn_id='spark_test_id',
    total_executor_cores=4,
    application='./plugins/plug_code.py',
    executor_cores=2,
    executor_memory='5g',
    driver_memory='5g',
    name='flight_search_ingestion',
    execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes=10),
    dag=dag
)
```

which gives me error JAVA HOME is  not set

in airflow cluster i dont have java, should i have java installed in airflow cluster as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need java install if you are using spark. what is the instance os?
you can check via:
`cat /etc/os-release` if it is a Linux based system.
Let's say it is ubuntu.
you can check available java versions:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

result should be like this:

```
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

you can set default java version like this:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

If java is not installed, you need to install it via (for example):

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
```

Comment: is java should be in airflow cluster?

Comment: seems like you are using spark in airflow cluster, if that's the case, yes, you need Java in Airflow cluster